# Properly deal with delimiters in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv looks like this:

```
Customername|"transactionkey"|"transactionamount"|"unitamount"

joe|"0001"|"100"|"100"

Alex|"0002"|"200"|"200"
```

In summary, the original file only has 1 column but many delimiters, which made the common `read_csv` not working. I am trying to load this dataset in python and transform it into a common dataframe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing your mention of `read_csv`, I think you may want to explicitly mention Pandas in the question and as a tag

Comment: Change the delimiter to |?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to read the file and replace all `"` with an empty string, then read it as you normally would with pandas read_csv.

```py
with open('file.csv', 'r+') as f:
    file = f.read()
    cleaned_file = file.replace('"', '')
    f.write(cleaned_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution, but given my limited knowledge of the task at hand.. You could load the file and manipulate it to your liking with Pandas.
could do something like this...

```
df_list = []
with open('filename.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        row_split = row.split('|')
        df_list.append(row)
    df = pandas.Dataframe(df_list)
```

then.... either can do

```
df.to_csv('fiename.csv', index=False)
```

or

loop through the dataframe and do what you needed to do with the csv like this...

```
for row, index in df.iterrows():
   do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the delimiter in `read_csv()`. It looks like the pipe character is your delimiter here `|`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='|')
```